# Copy files to new project and now cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, datasource

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

A Maven project in eclipse, I lost the .project file for this application. I have to copy the files into another project. So it was running before.

I am using a DataSource in Tomcat. The projects META-INF/context.xml file hasn't changed. It's deployed into /META-INF directory. web.xml and pom.xml is the same. I don't know what has changed. mysql-connector-5.1.38.jar is in $Catalina/lib.

I would look at the Build Path and Deployment Assembly but let me know.

[build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euR9X.jpg).
[deployment assly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XsnA.jpg).

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context> 
    <Resource 
        name="jdbc/widget" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="10" 
        maxIdle="3" 
        maxWait="10000"
        username="appuser" 
        password="appuserpass"  
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/widget"/>

</Context>
```

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>MySQL Datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/widget</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this, I saw a similar project and matched the deployment assembly. This seemed to fix the issue. Current configuration :

`/src/main/java -> WEB-INF/classes`

`/src/main/resources -> WEB-INF/classes`

`/src/main/resources/META-INF -> META-INF`

`/src/main/webapp -> /`

`/src/test/java -> WEB-INF/classes`

`Maven Dependencies -> WEB-INF/lib`